# "Dependency" definition

Tags: mathematical-statistics, correlation, variance, fitting

Origin Lab has in their fitting parameter's statistics "Dependency". Each parameter has *a* dependency. It's not like the covariance between 2 parameters. I thought it could be defined from all the covariances of the parameter with the others (i.e. with the covariance matrix) but I couldn't find any documentation.

I don't know if it's a general concept because I have zero knowledge in statistics. The main goal it's to implement it on Python, so if the definition is not trivial (e.g. aritmethic expressions), I would appreciate a function that can compute it.

Comment: Please supply a reference or clear quotation so that we aren't left to guess what you are asking about.

Comment: @whuber, I don't understand what do you mean, I'm sorry. If "Dependency" is a general concept, I'm asking for a definition. If it's not, and it's something Origin Lab made up, I'm asking to someone who knows about Origin Lab's definitions.

Comment: It is not a general concept.  A [tiny bit of Googling](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=origin+lab+parameter+dependency) (the third hit) produced the answer at https://www.originlab.com/doc/Origin-Help/NLFit-Theory#Dependency.

Comment: @whuber, thank you, I'm sorry for wasting your time. I looked into the programs help center and I found nothing. I also googled and got into the forums but still no answer. I should improve my googling skills. Thanks again.

Comment: Not a waste of time -- I learned something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For completness I will write an answer. Thanks to @whuber. It's defined in [the documentation](https://www.originlab.com/doc/Origin-Help/NLFit-Theory#Dependency) as

$$\text{Dependency}_i = 1 - \frac{1}{[\mathbf{C}]_{ii} \cdot [\mathbf{C}^{-1}]_{ii}},$$

where $\mathbf{C}$ is the covariance matrix.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the contributions @whuber and @MacroCiafa, I will include a Python implementation since that was your end goal. stats.SE is not primarily about coding, so consider this post merely a supplement to the accepted answer.

```py
import numpy as np

def dependence(X):
    '''
    Calculate the dependence of a 
    collection of variables from a data
    matrix.
   

    PARAMETERS
        X (2D array-like): Data matrix

    RETURNS
        (1D array): Dependence score of each variable.
    '''
    C = np.cov(X)
    result = np.diag(C) * np.diag(np.linalg.inv(C))
    return 1 - 1 / result
```

If you're fine with using the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse, then this can be adjusted slightly into the following.

```py
import numpy as np

def dependence(X):
    '''
    Calculate the dependence of a 
    collection of variables from a data
    matrix.
   

    PARAMETERS
        X (2D array-like): Data matrix

    RETURNS
        (1D array): Dependence score of each variable.
    '''
    C = np.cov(X)
    result = np.diag(C) * np.diag(np.linalg.pinv(C))
    return 1 - 1 / result
```